# Show different report layouts depending on the export format the user chooses

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Is there any way of changing the report layout depending on the export format chosen in SSRS?

When my report is exported to PDF with more than six columns in the table it overflows the page and creates an ugly layout. I would like to be able to limit the table to only showing a maximum of six columns when the report is exported to PDF. The report works fine when exported to Excel so I don't need to limit the columns in that case.

Comment: You would need someone with coding experience to edit the Report Viewer controls, and customise how it interacts with the reports.  Its not worth it quite frankly.

Comment: @bushell I need this because one record is broken into many pages in case of PDF format but it is not in case of Excel format. So, I want to show the error message to the user "Please print it in Excel format" in case of number of column exceeding.

Comment: I've made a pretty substantial edit to your question because I believe it is really an X/Y problem. (You're looking for a specific solution when other solutions may work even better to solve the actual problem you have.) If you don't agree with my edit feel free to roll it back or if you are unsure how to do that just respond and let me know and I'll do it for you.

Comment: On the columns you do not care to output to pdf simply put this in the hidden expression --> =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF",true,false)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot restrict the PDF export option based on the contents of the report. (At least not without some kind of intensive modifications to the PDF renderer... I wouldn't like to think what that would take.)

You **can** control the layout of the report based on the rendering type. There is a built-in global that will tell you which render format is being used.

```
 =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF",...
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you can hide certain elements and show others or limit the number of elements to be shown.

if you have a column group on the tablix you could try using a `Top N` filter or passing the render format to your SQL query to limit the number of values being returned for the column group. I haven't tried this though but I would imagine it would work. Of course if you do that you should have a note appear on the report so that the users know there is data that is being hidden because of the export format they've chosen or I'm sure you'll get at least a few calls about missing data.

Alternatively, I've used this in the past to show a simple table with all of the data in columns for the EXCEL render format and show a more complex & nicely formatted table for PDF export that I'm sure will fit on a page. This is just using the visible property on each of the tables with an expression checking the render format.

True, this is more effort because you have to create two elements that show the same information but it makes for a much more robust and useful report because it can be exported in the optimal layout for multiple formats.

Another use of this is to check the `Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive` property and expand collapsed sections that would otherwise be useless when exported to a format that you can't click on them in.

---

Resources:

- [Built-in Globals and Users References (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx)
- [Hide/Show Items Dependant On Export Format (SSRS)](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/) (shows the value of Globals!RenderFormat.Name for the default render engines)